# Efficient Replacing of Lowfrequent Elements in List of Lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that looks like the following:

```
[
 ['number_one', 'number_two', 3, 'number_six', 'fruit_apple'],
 ['number_one', 'fruit_apple' 'number_two', 'number_four'],
 ['number_two', 'number_two', 'fruit_apple' 'number_three', 'number_four', 4],
 ['number_three', 'fruit_apple' 'number_two', 'number_three', 'number_four'],
 ['number_four', 'fruit_apple' 'number_a_two', 'number_a_three', 'number_five', 'number_two', 9, 'fruit_orange'],
 ...
]
```

I want to replace all lowfrequent elements (say less than 2 occurrences across all lists) with a placeholder. For example if an integer element has less than 2 occurrences it's getting replaced by `integer_placeholder`, if an string element starting with `number_` has less than 2 occurrences it's getting replaced by `stringnumber_placeholder`. Same for the fruits.

Expected result (for a threshold of 2):

```
[
 ['number_one', 'number_two', 'integer_placeholder', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'fruit_apple'],
 ['number_one', 'fruit_apple' 'number_two', 'number_four'],
 ['number_two', 'number_two', 'fruit_apple' 'number_three', 'number_four', 'integer_placeholder'],
 ['number_three', 'fruit_apple' 'number_two', 'number_three', 'number_four'],
 ['number_four', 'fruit_apple' 'number_a_two', 'number_a_three', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'number_two', 'integer_placeholder', 'fruit_placeholder'],
 ...
]
```

Of course this could be done with iterating at least two times over the list and some nested loops. But is there any **short**, **simple**, **efficient** way to do this?

EDIT: My list contains 4881 sublists with each sublist containing 992 elements on average

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `collections.Counter()` to count the instances and then a loop to do my replacements in-place. Like so:

```
a = [
 ['number_one', 'number_two', 3, 'number_six'],
 ['number_one', 'number_two', 'number_four'],
 ['number_two', 'number_two', 'number_three', 'number_four', 4],
 ['number_three', 'number_two', 'number_three', 'number_four'],
 ['number_four', 'number_a_two', 'number_a_three', 'number_five', 'number_two', 9]
]

from collections import Counter as cC

c = cC(x for y in a for x in y)  # generator expression to flatten the list of lists

replacement = {int: 'integer_placeholder', str: 'string_placeholder'}

thres = 2
for i, sub in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = [x if c[x] >= thres else replacement[type(x)] for x in sub]
```

---

If you want to avoid recreating the `sublists` as it is done above with the list-comprehension you can do it the @Alfe way.

```
thres = 2
for i, sub in enumerate(a):
    for j, item in enumerate(sub):
        if cC[item] < thres:
            sub[i][j] = replacement[type(x)]
```

The replacements are inserted using the `replacement` `dict` that works based on the type of item we are replacing.

For the record, the above (with `thres = 2`) produces

```
[['number_one', 'number_two', 'integer_placeholder', 'string_placeholder'],
 ['number_one', 'number_two', 'number_four'],
 ['number_two', 'number_two', 'number_three', 'number_four', 'integer_placeholder'],
 ['number_three', 'number_two', 'number_three', 'number_four'],
 ...]
```

Notice the placeholders.

---

If you want to be even more flexible when it comes to assigning the correct placeholder you can go with something like this:

```
def placeholder_selector(something):
    if 'fruits' in something:
        return 'fruit_placeholder'
    elif ...
        return 'string_placeholder'
    ....
```

and

```
for i, sub in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = [x if c[x] >= thres else placeholder_selector(x) for x in sub]
```

Comment: How would one use generic conditions instead of types? E.g. ``strings`` starting with ``number_`` (to quote me).

Comment: Would you mind explaining that a bit more? Are you having quoted numbers like `"3"` for example you are worried about?

Comment: No, I just have other strings that I want to replace with other placeholders like a string ``fruits_apple`` potentially replaced by ``fruits_placeholder`` etc.

Comment: Your solution creates new sublists and replaces the original ones.  I think replacing only elements in the sublists is more efficient.

Comment: @Alfe This might very well be the case. I think it boils down to how frequently changes are going to be made. If a lot of elements have to be replaced by their placeholders and the sublists are relatively small, I do not think it makes a difference. If that is not the case, sure.

Comment: My list contains 4881 sublists with each sublist containing 992 elements on average.

Comment: The step that takes the longest in my code would definitely be the creation of the `Counter` dict. All in all, this should be relatively fast. I could jmplement @Alfe's remarks as an alternative and maybe you OP could time them for us?

Answer (score 1):

Do it in three steps:  First: iterate through all lists and count which element comes how often, second: filter out all elements which have a low count, third: step through all lists and replace the elements which are in the list of low-count elements.

```
counter = defaultdict(int)
for sublist in sublists:
  for element in sublist:
    counter[element] += 1
low_count_elements = { element
  for element, count in counter.iteritems()
  if count < 5 }
for sublist in sublists:
  for i in range(len(sublist)):
    if sublist[i] in low_count_elements:
      sublist[i] = placeholder
```

I would recommend to replace the variable name `sublist` by something more suitable, but lacking context, I cannot come up with a more fitting name.

In case you are using Python 3, use `items()` instead of `iteritems()`.

Regarding your concern about short, simple, efficient:  Using Python, I dare you to find a **shorter** or **simpler** solution.  Returning a copy instead of replacing the elements inline will not be more **efficient**.  The task you ask for is by its nature one which needs to iterate twice.  I cannot see any way to optimize this away (by using a more clever algorithm).  You could use a subsample of your data to find out which elements are how often, in case we are talking about large numbers of elements.  This might be a pragmatic optimization step which of course comes with a small error.  And of course you could be more efficient if you were using a specialized library like `numpy` which can do many steps in optimized C instead of explicit Python.

Comment: How about the very creative `sublist`? Also would be good to mention that you are using Python 2 (`iteritems()`)

Comment: I adopted this, but still think that, given a context, a more fitting name is likely to be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

If you have very few low-frequent elements, it might be an optimization to memorize the positions of these **instead of iterating twice** over everything.  You then would only iterate over the few elements.

```
low_counter = defaultdict(set)
high_set = set()
for i, sublist in enumerate(sublists):
  for j, element in enumerate(sublist):
    if element not in high_set:
      c = len(low_counter[element])
      if c + 1 < 5:
        low_counter[element].add((i, j))
      elif c + 1 == 5:
        del low_counter[element]
        high_set.add(element)
for i, j in low_counter:
  sublists[i][j] = placeholder
```

But of course, from a certain amount of such elements upwards (e. g. if nearly every element is to be replaced), this is way less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `collections.Counter` subclass:

```
import collections, itertools

l = [
 ['number_one', 'number_two', 3, 'number_six', 'fruit_apple'],
 ['number_one', 'fruit_apple', 'number_two', 'number_four'],
 ['number_two', 'number_two', 'fruit_apple' 'number_three', 'number_four', 4],
 ['number_three', 'fruit_apple', 'number_two', 'number_three', 'number_four'],
 ['number_four', 'fruit_apple', 'number_a_two', 'number_a_three', 'number_five', 'number_two', 9, 'fruit_orange'],
]

limit = 2
counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
for sub_l in l:
    for k,i in enumerate(sub_l):
        sub_l[k] = i if counts[i] > limit else ('integer_placeholder' if isinstance(i,int) else 'stringnumber_placeholder')

print(l)
```

The output:

```
[['stringnumber_placeholder', 'number_two', 'integer_placeholder', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'fruit_apple'], ['stringnumber_placeholder', 'fruit_apple', 'number_two', 'number_four'], ['number_two', 'number_two', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'number_four', 'integer_placeholder'], ['stringnumber_placeholder', 'fruit_apple', 'number_two', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'number_four'], ['number_four', 'fruit_apple', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'stringnumber_placeholder', 'number_two', 'integer_placeholder', 'stringnumber_placeholder']]
```

Comment: this is almost identical to mine.